# Change the values of the combo-box based on selection of other combo box for a j2ee

Tags: javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, combobox

This seems to be a chewed out question but almost all the answers I found were for the desktop application which uses 'itemStateChanged' for detecting the change in the value of the combo box and then updating the other combo boxes. But so far I have not found any acceptable answers in terms of a web application(J2EE). So what should I use to update the combo boxes dynamically,
Eg,
I have 3 combo boxes branch, semester, subjects. Now based on the value of selected for branch and semester the value for the 'subjects' combo box should change. Should I use Javascript or JSP-Servlets for my task.
This seemed to be an opinion based question but that's what I'm looking for. Kindly tell me the pros and cons of using Javascript or 'JSP-Servlets'.
Many thanks.

Comment: The browser does not know anything about JSP and Servlets, so the only option which is left is Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be answered generally without knowing how you build your web application.

The "default" way to make a server-based web application with Java EE is JSF. And there you'd use AJAX to handle changes for your combo boxes on the server side by connecting a handler to your 1st combo box, update the model of the others and rerender the container with the combo boxes.

Comment: what do you mean by "default" way? What about JSP?

Comment: JSF is the standard way to build server based web applications within the Java EE framework. JSP is one view technology, which can be used within JSF applications and was the default since Java EE 5. Java EE 6 replaced that with the Facelets technology, which is still the case for Java EE 7. So if you have the chance to use a current Java EE, you don't have to use JSPs any longer, but you can of course still do so.